# How do I get the index of a node by value

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

So I was making a code editor (It is a fusion between Visual Studio Code and the Python IDLE) in C# WFA (Windows Form Application). I was making the project explorer where I faced many issues, mainly being:

I have found the solution get the files displayed under the sub-directories but if I use the way I am using to add files into the main directory, it will add all the files of all sub-directories in one sub-directory. I found out that the solution to this is that I get the index of the node by using it's value. I googled some properties of Nodes and the tree view but I couldn't find a function to do so. So Like any ideas on How I add the files of the specific subdirectory under that directory only?

Code:

My ProjectBase:

```
public ProjectBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuStrip1.Renderer = new myRenderer();
        label1.Text = ProjectCreation.ProjectName;
        string FolderPath = ProjectCreation.rootDir;
        string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath);
        string[] folderArray = Directory.GetDirectories(FolderPath);
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(FolderPath);
        foreach (string folder_name in folderArray)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(folder_name);
            string[] fileArrray2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder_name);
            foreach (string file_name2 in fileArrray2)
            {
 
            }
        }
        foreach (string file_name in fileArray)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(file_name);
        }
    }
```

Choose Path for Project Creatiion (I use this area to get the rootDir or the working directory)

```
dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Project Creation Path";
        dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;
 
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            folder = dlg.FileName;
            rootDir = Functions.GetLastPathSegment(folder);
        }
```

My Project Manger Open Project Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectCreation.dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        ProjectCreation.dlg.Title = "Open New Project";
        ProjectCreation.dlg.IsFolderPicker = true;

        if (ProjectCreation.dlg.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            ProjectCreation.folder = ProjectCreation.dlg.FileName;
            
            ProjectCreation.rootDir = Functions.GetLastPathSegment(ProjectCreation.folder);
            
            ProjectBase project_new = new ProjectBase();
            project_new.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post links to code - instead, include all the relevant code *in the question*, ideally as a [mcve]. Readers shouldn't have to visit a bunch of links in order to understand your question.

Comment: "Well it's a lot. I mean A TON. Thats why I posted links" - does it have to be though? Is *every part* of your current code required in order to reproduce the problem? I'd be surprised if that were the case. Reduce it to the bare minimum, and I suspect it then won't be too much to post.

Comment: Additionally, currently your post is about two different things. Each post should be about *one* problem. The "showing the entire path" and the "everything is added to one subdirectory" problems are separate, and should be in separate posts.

Comment: The question is still really unclear to me, particularly "I found out that the solution to this is that I get the index of the node by using it's value." The fact that you don't do anything with the contents of `fileArrray2` is somewhat suspicious... where do you *believe* you are actually creating a full tree instead of just a single node with child nodes under that? (I'd expect there to be recursion involved...)